# SQL database log migration after data migration sql server

Tags: sql-server, database, azure, azure-sql-database

I have on prim database I want to migrate database to azure sql database.

First I am using migration service to migrate database and it will take 10 hours to migrate, but the records get insert, update and delete during this migration.

How can I update the target sql azure database with updated one.

Comment: Is your on-premise database running SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and many times the quickest way to migrate an on-premise database to Azure SQL Database is using Data Migration Assistant. Please give it a try. Download it from here.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595

Comment: I am using same DMA and DMS to migrate data. The database size is over 2TB.

Comment: You mean you already migrated the 2 TB database and now you want update it with changes on-premise database?

Comment: If you wish to update your Azure SQL Database to incorporate changes made to your SQL Server on-premise database, you can use Azure Data Sync (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-sync-data) or transactional replication (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/transactional/transactional-replication).